# How to play a video and run content at the same time

Tags: xna, c#, video, layers

Alright, so I have a video loaded, and other game content.

Earlier this morning, when I was just learning how to actually play a video, I magically happened to get the video running in the background, and also keep everything else drawn above it. I was thrilled and thought I will easily manage to do the rest.

Now that I'm almost done, I have several videos that I want to draw. I made a loop that will only run one time as an intro, and then after it stops, it sequences one of the other videos, but the thing is, this next video is drawn above everything else, while the rest of my game content, is "under" the Rectangle where the video Texture is running, can anyone help me on how to get a Rectangle variable "behind" everything? almost as a background? Thanks a lot!

Comment: playing a video as a background of a game, is absolutely terrible for performance

Comment: @Shiro It's a very simple game, barely 2 sprites of less than 40x40 pixels. I don't think I need to worry about performance just yet.